# Proper way to use on click functions to expand a div in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, typescript, react-redux

I want to achieve this effect using react

https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/1400/3abb6f41658891.57b122eb4e3eb.jpg,

in the part that looks like a ticket when u click it expands, i already have the top part which looks like a ticket, what is the correct to expand the div in react?

edit here is how im rendering each "ticket" component,

```
     export class RepoListItem extends React.PureComponent { // eslint-   disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
    render() {



const item = this.props.item;

var dateObj = item.dates.start.localDate;
var date = dateObj.split('-')[2];
var year = dateObj.split('-')[0];
var month = months[parseInt(dateObj.split('-')[1]) - 1];

let nameprefix = '';

var minPrice = parseInt(item.priceRanges[0].min);
var maxPrice = parseInt(item.priceRanges[0].max);



for(var i = 0; i < item.images.length; i++){
    if(item.images[i].ratio == "16_9" && item.images[i].width == 1024)
    {
    var artistcover = item.images[i].url;
    }
}

// Put together the content of the repository
const content = (


  <Container>
    <DateResultWrap>
          <DateResult_h1 >
            {date}
          </DateResult_h1 >
          <DateResult_p>{month}</DateResult_p>
          <DateResult_p3>{year}</DateResult_p3>
          <SpanDiv>
          <Span />
          </SpanDiv>
          <DateResult_p2>{item._embedded.venues[0].name}</DateResult_p2>
    </DateResultWrap>
        <ResultImgWrap>
          <Img src={artistcover} alt="artist_cover" />
        </ResultImgWrap>
        <ResultDescriptionWrap>
            <DescriptionTitle>
                <TitleH1> {item._embedded.attractions[0].name} </TitleH1>
                <PlaceDescription> ({item._embedded.venues[0].city.name} / {item._embedded.venues[0].state.name}) </PlaceDescription>
                <ArrowHiddenIcon className="material-icons">&#xE317;</ArrowHiddenIcon>
            </DescriptionTitle>
            <ResultDescriptionPCont> 
              <ResultDescription_P>
                 {item._embedded.attractions[0].name} will be performing at {item._embedded.venues[0].name} for her {item.promoter.name}
                 <br />
                 Event starts: {item.dates.start.localTime}, timezone: {item.dates.timezone}
                 <br />
                 Please Note: {item.pleaseNote}
                 <br />
                 Tickets on sale now for : ${minPrice} - ${maxPrice}



              </ResultDescription_P>
            </ResultDescriptionPCont>
        </ResultDescriptionWrap>

    </Container>

);

// Render the content into a list item
return (
  <ListItem key={`repo-list-item-${item._embedded.events}`} item={content}          />
  );
 }
 }

  RepoListItem.propTypes = {
    item: React.PropTypes.object,
    currentUser: React.PropTypes.string,
  };

  export default connect(createStructuredSelector({
     currentUser: makeSelectCurrentUser(),
  }))(RepoListItem);
```

Comment: you have to give some code for people to work on and help you with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it using css, listening to `onClick` on the div and toggle some css classes when the div is clicked. Here's some sample code I wrote.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

class componentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      expandedTicket: false,
    }
    this.toggleExpandedTicket = this.toggleExpandedTicket.bind(this);
  }
  toggleExpandedTicket() {
    this.setState({ expandedTicket: !this.state.expandedTicket, });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
         {
           // Listening on onClick event in the following div
           // And toggling css classes expanded-ticket and normal-ticket accordingly
         }
        <div
          className={`row ${this.state.expandedTicket ? 'expanded-ticket' : 'normal-ticket'}`}
          onClick={this.toggleExpandedTicket}
        >
          {
            // Using bootstrap
            // Use your own columns, this is untested
          }
          <div className="col-md-1 date">
            {
              // I use moment for parsing and displaying dates, safely ignore this
            }
            {moment(date).format('D')}
            <br />
            {moment(date).format('MMM')}
            <br />
            {moment(date).format('YYYY')}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-8 image">
            <img src="" alt=""/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-3 description">
            Description
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default componentName
```

Feel free to ask for clarifications